# How to enable/disable a column in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been using jQuery for my client side applications. I have started using `angular js`. I have a data grid populated with values from DB.

1. If i click on add button, a new data row will be created. On clicking the inline edit, I can add new properties
2. I can directly click on the inline edit. And modify the existing data.
   [image: Mock screen of the data grid]

My problem is, User should be able to add the *ID, name and comments* when it is a new data row.
For the already existing data rows, the *ID* field should be disabled.

I am new to `angular JS`. I tried to set ng-readonly. But it always makes the *ID* field read only.

Please help me in addressing this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) for that:

```
<input type='text' ng-disabled="<condition>" />
```

Comment: But will it not make the ID field disabled always ? I want the user to set the custom ID value if it is a new row/data.

Comment: <condition> is a boolean condition you can write based on what you need. you can write ng-disabled="currRow.Id.length > 0" for example.

Comment: Condition is an expression which returns a boolean. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Comment: @Amiros : 
<tr ng-repeat="data in dataList">
<td style="float:none; vertical-align:middle;">
<span style="display:inline-block;
....     ng-disabled="data.ID.length()>0" e-required> {{ data.ID || 'ID' }} </span>
</td>
still the same issue exists :(

Comment: I can't guess how your model looks like. If you want me to look into it then create a fiddle or something..